# inline multiple matching within a search string in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have OpenGL code for which I would like to have some special indentation after running astyle. For example,

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex2f(1.0f, 2.0f);
glVertex2f(1.0f, 2.0f);
glVertex2f(1.0f, 2.0f);
glVertex2f(1.0f, 2.0f);
glEnd();
```

The above code I want to change to some thing like below.

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2f(1.0f, 2.0f);
    glVertex2f(1.0f, 2.0f);
    glVertex2f(1.0f, 2.0f);
    glVertex2f(1.0f, 2.0f);
glEnd();
```

In this special case whatever is there in between glBegin and glEnd I want to shift by 4 white spaces.

I want to do this inline and using perl.

Comment: What do you mean by inline?  If you mean in the command line then you need to specify operating system.

Comment: By inline I meant using -e option

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say what you mean by "inline."  I assume you want to use the `-e` command line option.  This is a pretty simple use of perl.  You should spend some time with the documentation.  In Windows cmd shell:

```
perl -p -e "$i=0 if/glEnd/;s/^/    / if $i;$i=1 if /glBegin/" < infile.c > outfile.c
```

**In bash replace the double quotes with single ones.**

Comment: @user1429924 Good.  It would be nice if you accepted the answer then.